# How do you access a model attribute with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm adding an attribute to my `ModelAndView` in spring and after this i forwarding it to my thymeleaf view.

In the view i have the following code:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            var applicationName = /*[[${T(com.sample.constants.ApplicationConstants).MODEL_ATTR_COLLECTED_VALUES}]]*/ "Test";
            var collectedValueJson = [[${collectedValues}]];
            console.log(collectedUserJson);
        /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Result from this is

```
var applicationName = 'collectedValues';
var collectedUserJson = '[{\"givenname\":\"Muster\",\"surname\":\"Peter\"}]';
```

That's fine. Now my wish for this is, that i can take the `var application` and access with this variable the modelattribute, but that's not working.

Result is this:

```
var tmp2 = ${applicationName};
```

An other try was, that i have access to the modelattribute with the syntax  `/*[[ ]]*/` from the first try:

```
var applicationName = ${/*[[${T(com.sample.constants.ApplicationConstants).MODEL_ATTR_COLLECTED_VALUES}]]*/};
```

But result will be:

```
var tmp = ${'collectedValues'
```

i have no idea what can i try.

Any other suggestions?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: if your purpose is to communicate data from the back-end to js see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768947/thymeleaf-javascript-inlining-and-iteration/26780798#26780798

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no way you can access model atributes hence they are on server side and they where lost when rendering jsp into HTML

Comment: This is false as Spring Boot provides with the model to pass the atributes so it can be rendered by Thymeleaf.

Comment: @CarlosLópezMarí does Thymeleaf not resolve the view at server side itself

Comment: @AB It does, but the rendered view can contain any given values. Just as the html.

Comment: He doesn't need to do it after rendering if I understood correctly

Answer (score 5):

There is a workaround worth mentioning: Write out the attribute to

```
<span id="myvar" th:text="${attributeName}"></span>
```

and then read it in with JavaScript using

```
document.getElementById("myvar").value
```

or some similar jQuery call:

```
$('#myvar').text()
```

Comment: spans `value` may give `undefined`. you can use `span.innerHTML`

Answer (score 3):

You can:

```
<span id="span_id" style="display: none;" th:text="${attributeName}"></span>
```

and then in your Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("span_id").innerHTML
```