# Reload div with new attributes

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

I have a div:

```
<div class="textWord_about" data-link="first">
  <br/><br/>
  <br/><br/><br/>
  <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr style="margin-right:0;">
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Follower Number</th>
      <th>Following Number</th>
      <th>Profile</th>
      <th>Created At</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="follower:${followers}" style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <td th:text="${api.getHash(follower.getScreenName())}"></td>
      <td th:text="${follower.getFollowersCount()}"></td>
      <td th:text="${follower.getFriendsCount()}"></td>
      <td><a th:href="@{'/viewprofile'(id=${follower.getId()})}">profile</a></td>
      <td th:text="${follower.getCreatedDate()}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I used Jquery and Ajax to get a new value for `followers` from the server. 
The problem is that how can I set this new value using Jquery?

I have tried something like this:

```
$('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this)
    .data('button-link-followerList') + ']')
    .attr('followers', data.followers);
```

the Script with Ajax request is this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".button-link-followerList").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $post = $(this);
        var href = $($post).attr("id");
        var currentCredit_followerList = parseInt($('#_followerList_credit').text());
        console.log("herf: " + href);
        if (currentCredit_followerList != 0) {
            console.log("condition checked!");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: href,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data.status == "success") {
                    var newCredit_followerList = currentCredit_followerList - 1;
                    $('#_followerList_credit').text(newCredit_followerList);
                    $('.mainContainer').hide();
                    $('.textWord_about > table > tbody > tr').remove();

                    $.each(followers, function (index, obj) {
                        var row = '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + obj.screenName() + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + obj.followersCount + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + obj.friendsCount + '</td>' +
                            '<td><a href="/viewprofile' + '?id=' + obj.id + '">profile</a></td>' +
                            '<td>' + obj.createdDate + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>';
                        $('.textWord_about > table > tbody').append(row);
                    });

                    $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('button-link-followerList') + ']').fadeIn({width: '200px'}, 300);
                    return false;
                }
                else if (data.status == "ratelimit") {
                    window.location.href = "ratelimit";
                }
            });

        } else {
            // Show Alarm!
            $('#_credit_error').fadeIn(100);
        }
    })
});
```

But, the console log says that the `followers` is undefined. As a result, I can not see my `div` with its new value.

Note: In the very first load the page which contains the `div`, it is hidden and the `followers` does not have any value.

Comment: you can not add attribute which is not available in html. followers is not an html attribute. Instead of this use data attribute like data-followers

Comment: Yes you can try this : $('.textWord_about[data-link=' + $(this).data('button-link-followerList') + ']').data('followers',data.followers);

Comment: @Kashyap this solution needs some changes in div, doesn't it?! It does not work and the followers is still undefined!

Comment: @YeganehHajimiri what does the ajax request return? A json containing the the list of followers or rendered html?

Comment: @JakubCh. it returns  a json containing the list of followers. this is the response: jsonResponseObject.put("followers",listOfTwitterProfiles.getTwitterProfiles());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **th:** attributes guide Thymeleaf, how to render some static elements in the output html, but don't provide any special attributes. When you check the page's source using the web browser's inspector, you will see an oridnary content inside `<tbody>`, without any `followers` e.g.

```
<tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td><a href="/viewprofile?id=1">profile</a></td>
    <td>01-08-2017</td>
</tr>
```

You receive JSON from server so if you want to add/replace values you have to manipulate DOM using jQuery. You can take advantage of jQuery methods `remove()`, `each()` and `append()`

**Firstly** remove old rows (if you want to replace old followers with the new ones) .

```
$('.textWord_about > table > tbody > tr').remove();
```

**Secondly** iterate through followers' list, which you've received from server. For each object append new row with suitable data.

```
$.each(data.followers, function(index, obj) {
    var row = '<tr><td>' + obj.screenName() + '</td><td>' + obj.followersCount + '</td><td>' + obj.friendsCount + '</td><td><a href="/viewprofile' + '?id=' + obj.id + '">profile</a></td><td>' + obj.createdDate + '</td><td></tr>';
    $('.textWord_about > table > tbody').append(row);
});
```

This should resolve your issue.

<strike>**Note:** I used Thymeleaf syntax inside the script (`[[ @{'/viewprofile'} ]]`) to evaluate proper link adress, so please remember to put the entire script into the tag with js inlining: `<script th:inline='javascript'>`.</strike>

**Note** I hardcoded URL to profile view and this should be fine. Otherwise, if  you want to evaluate them using thymeleaf's `@{}` syntax, you have to apply [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27214381/5684265). Provide an inline script inside html file, which evaluates your url and assign it to the variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" >
    var viewprofileUrlPrefix = [[ @{'/viewprofile'} ]]
</script>
```

and then simply use that variable in your js file while appending:

```
'<a href="' + viewprofileUrlPrefix + '?id=' + obj.id
```

**Note2:** I skipped the part with `api.getHash( ... )` as I don't know what it is doing. I assumed that received JSON would contain the proper value, so you don't have to evaluate it via javascript. This would be the most convenient.

Comment: I want to do this remove() and append() methods after returning from Ajax request successfully.And my scripts are in a .js file. Considering this, where should I put these 2 lines of codes? It is not inline script, so the Note is not applicable!

Comment: Yeah, removing and appending should be placed inside success method after returning from Ajax request. In that case you could try apply link to "viewprofile" without `@{}` syntax. However if it is necessary then you could apply [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27214381/5684265). I've updated my answer.

Comment: I get an error that followers(in $.each(... ) is not defined!

Comment: I did not change my div (in the question). Based on this solution, is it correct?

Comment: @YeganehHajimiri could you update your question with code responsible for ajax request?

Comment: @YeganehHajimiri replace `followers` with `data.followers` inside `$.each`. If it doesn't work, debbug how `data` object looks like, because an array containing followers is somewhere inside it.  Variable called `followers` woudn't come out of nowhere!