# Thymeleaf: How to get environment variable in js file not html

Tags: spring, environment-variables, thymeleaf

I am using `thymleaf` engine.
I can get `environment variable` in `.html` file. But I failed to get `environment variable` in `.js` file. How to get `environment variable` in `.js` file not `.html` ?

The following code shows result when I defined `environment variable` in `.js` and  `.html`

application.properties

```
huge=huge
```

When I defined `environment variable` in `foo.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
hugeOfHtml = "[[${@environment.getProperty('huge')}]]";
</script>
```

The result in chrome F12

```
<script type="text/javascript">
hugeOfHtml = "huge";
</script>
```

In contrast to When I defined `environment variable` in `foo.js`

```
hugeOfJs = "[[${@environment.getProperty('huge')}]]";
```

The result in chrome F12

```
hugeOfJs = "[[${@environment.getProperty('huge')}]]";
```

How to get `environment variable` in `.js` file not `.html` ?

Comment: Maybe take out the '@' symbol?  In my code, and in examples I can find on the net, there is never an @ sign after the curly brace.  In some cases, there is an @ before a curly brace, but that's not for variable expansion.  The other possibility is that the .js file isn't being run through Thymeleaf at all.  Is anything different between the template file and the resulting file?  You have given us no information about why you expect your .js file to be going through Thymeleaf.

Comment: @CryptoFool Thank you for your answer. I took out '@'. But result is same. I think  '.js file isn't being run through Thymeleaf at all' too. The reason I want this, I only don't want to write variable of javasciprt in .html file

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  If you want to run your JS file through Thymeleaf, you have to set up a controller that returns JavaScript just like you have a controller to run html.

Comment: You should check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67584707/4076291 It treats a html thymeleaf fragment file as an external JS library.

Comment: @Metroids Thank you for your answer. I will try that. But It looks like takes time and effort

Comment: @Ahmet Thank your for your answer. It works very well. But I think that environment variable is  declared on html file not js file in that solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using spring boot 2 and thymeleaf 3. Most probably the externalized js file is located in the `src/resources/static/` path and if so, then thymeleaf will not process it. Now say you move it to another directory `src/resources/templates/js/`, thymeleaf should process the externalized js file and give the result which you were expecting as you asked.

However given the externalized js file is not a static resource anymore, you will have to expose a get method in your controller to load the externalized js file. The method will look like so;

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @GetMapping("/js/foo.js")
    public String loadFooDotJs(){
        return "/js/foo.js";
    }
}
```

The method above will load the externalized js file, process it using thymeleaf and return it accordingly.

If you are using just spring; not spring boot, I believe you will have to create the template resolver and template engine as well. [Here is a good article by Baeldung](https://baeldung-cn.com/spring-thymeleaf-3).